# Has_and_belongs_to_many index mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a many to many relations between users and projects, and it works perfectly. However I want to model this scenario in **mongoid**:

```
db.projects.insert(
  { 
    "name" : "Test project",
    "memberships" : [
      {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("4d730fcfcedc351d67000002"),
        "role" : "administrator"
      },
      {
        "role" : "editor",
        "user_id" : ObjectId("4d731fe3cedc351fa7000002")
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

I read the documentation for Mongoid, and for relations I have to do this:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :preferences, index: true
```

And create like this:

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

But when I persist, it saves the relationship but the index isn't created. [Modeling many-to-many :through with Mongoid/MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209072/modeling-many-to-many-through-with-mongoid-mongodb) asks exactly the same question, but the answer does not show how to do it in Mongoid unless I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a project record of many-to-many association with Users:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("53148dae69616db0c7000000"), 
    "user_ids" : 
    [   
      ObjectId("53148dbd69616db0c7010000"),     
      ObjectId("53148dc169616db0c7020000") 
     ] 
 }
```

and the related index will look like this:

```
  {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "user_ids" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mydb.projects",
    "background" : true,
    "name" : "user_ids_1"
   }
```

The one you posted has 'membership' subdocuments which are the ones who has the association with User. To index user_ids in this case you need to do something like

```
db.projects.ensureIndex({"memberships.user_id": 1})
```